# PyQt5 create error upon failed dbus request

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, dbus

Using PyQt5's D-Bus, how do I create an error? For example, if someone sends an unknown command in a chat program, I'd like to be able to let the client know something like as follows:

```
error = QDBusMessage.createError(QDBusError.UnknownProperty, "unknown command")
QDBusConnection.systemBus().send(error)
```

However, this fails with the message:

```
*** TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  createErrorReply(self, str, str): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QDBusMessage'
  createErrorReply(self, QDBusError): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QDBusMessage'
  createErrorReply(self, QDBusError.ErrorType, str): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QDBusMessage'
```

I can't make heads no tail of this error, since as far as I can tell I'm using it exactly as described. The first arg must be QDBusMessage, since that's what's before the dot. The second arg is of the right type, being `<class 'PyQt5.QtDBus.QDBusError.ErrorType'>` as returned by `type(QDBusError.UnknownProperty)`. And the quotes mean it's a string, which is what `str` is.

I also tried [sendErrorReply()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbuscontext.html#sendErrorReply), but that doesn't seem to exist in PyQt5. At least, I can't find it - it's not beside `systemBus`'s `send()`, and it's not found in `QDBusMessage`.

Neither of the examples in PyQt5's `examples/dbus/chat` folder emit errors. There is no Python documentation available at http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtDBus.html.

Comment: The `self` argument shown in the output is giving you a big clue, which is then made explicit by this: "first argument of unbound method must have type 'QDBusMessage'". So you need to call `createErrorReply` on an ***instance*** of `QDBusMessage`. Or to put it another way: `createErrorReply` is not a class/static method.

Comment: That does construct an error, but I still can't send the error. Upon calling `QDBusConnection.systemBus().send(error)`, I get the message "process 25541: arguments to dbus_message_get_sender() were incorrect, assertion "message != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 3437."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across your question when I had the same problem as you, a lack of `sendErrorReply` in PyQt5.

Here's how I got it to work in my Bluetooth application:

```
@pyqtSlot(QDBusMessage)
    def AuthorizeService(self, message):
        print("rejecting service authorization")
        error = message.createErrorReply(QDBusError.AccessDenied, "Failed")
        self._bus.send(error)
```

The trick is to create the error reply from the message that was received.